# Brackets go backward on Unicode text

Tags: asp.net, text, dynamic

I have Unicode text being displayed on an ASP.NET page. The text is enclosed by two square brackets, as soon as Arabic text appears the ending bracket goes reverse, e.g.
"`[Hi there]`" becomes "`[ [arabic`". Is this a browser issue? The brackets are hard-coded and only the enclosing text is dynamic.

Here is some sample code. The variable `resultString` contains the Unicode text.

```
<%
Response.Write("[" + resultString+ "]  ");
%>
```

Comment: Can you provide any sample code? Such as how the element is being displayed (as in, `[<asp:Literal ID="somesuch" runat="server">blah</aspLiteral>]` etc)

Comment: Is it perhaps going RTL without a later LTR and catching up the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing to not be stupid.  This should do what you want.

```
<%
    string resultString = "العربية";
    Response.Write("<p dir = \"LTR\"> [" + resultString + "]</p>  ");
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the string properly padded with RTL/LTR marks? (Unicodes U+200E and U+200F unless I'm mistaken). That is usually required to make bidirectional text behave as expected in normal applications, though I'm not sure how it applies to a web page.